# Google Drive and the fullscreen issue in Safari (iPad)

Tags: iframe

I uploaded a video to Google Drive and I created a blog in Blogspot. Then, I inserted a code like this in one of my blog posts:

```
iframe width="560" height="315"
src="http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B21fQyiIJBBnWms0S2UyaUFNeWM/preview" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" / iframe
```

I have tested the code under the following conditions and get the following results:

1. When using my PC, I can go to fullscreen and select the video quality/subtitles (another button);
2. When using Safari for iPad, I can see the video quality/subtitles button, but can't go to fullscreen;
3. When using Mercury Browser for iPAD with user-agent "Safari (iPhone Mobile)", I can't see/use the video quality/subtitles button, but now I am able to go fullscreen;
4. Google Drive's app from App Store can't use the video quality/subtitles button, but is also able to go fullscreen;
5. Puffin browser (app from App Store) is able to use the video quality/subtitles button and go fullscreen. However I stopped using this for 2 reasons:

   - Video takes a lot of time to load. In Safari, it takes a couple of seconds. Using Puffin, over 10. Don't know why, but it looks like it's either my iPad that is slow (4th gen, last iOS), or this is to be expected;
   - Even when the video is playing, it looks like playback is stuttering. I mean, not running smoothly, as the same browser does in the Youtube website. BTW, Puffin supports Flash, but until recently, this functionality was paid and lasted only a short time;

---

My questions are:

1. why is 2) happening?
2. Can it be fixed by using another CODE in my personal blog/website or I do need to wait for future iOS updates?

   ---

Also, Youtube's iframe allows us to go fullscreen in Safari from iPad. Which means Google is to be blamed (I guess) for this to happen with Google-Drive.

I wonder if there's a way to bypass this restriction, and force the player to go fullscreen, also showing subtitles, as it happens with Youtube.

Comment: How is your question about a programming or coding? As written, it is probably too broad for this site. (If you had a specific code question, your question might fit on this site).

Comment: Did you read the entire post? I am asking if there's a way to bypass this restriction.

I also found this link in here, making me confused, I thought Google was preventing Safari from going fullscreen:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Can you explain what I am missing here?

Are there no workarounds for me to watch this in fullscreen? Try using my code elsewhere and try watching in Safari/iPAD, you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: I am sorry. I was overzealous when skimming your question. That being said, your question was poorly formatted and difficult to read, hence my confusion when reading it. I have suggested edits to your question to improve its readability (my edits need to be reviewed before they will show up and I don't know if you can view them).

Comment: The post was fine but somehow the iframe code was swallowed, I fixed now. One more thing: I added subtitle to a Internet Archive video. Tried to play in Safari (iPAD). Fullscreen works. Subtitle works. But the subtitle somehow vanishes when going fullscreen! This is a sure sign something is wrong with this tablet in terms of supporting what I need: videos going fullscreen and subtitles being displayed. So far only Youtube does both using an iframe code, which raises these questions: a new code can bypass this restriction? Who should be blamed? The video hosting sites or Apple?